# "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I add this line of code in my PHP code ...

```
echo 'document.write("<input type="hidden" />");';
```

... I obtain this error .... (note that is javascript code writed from PHP code  ...).

This is only a sample because my original code is more complex

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I've tried to escape the code in different manner but no result

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance ...

Cesare

Comment: You need to close off your quotes

Answer (score 3):

Look at your quotes. You have double quotes inside of double quotes.  This terminates your string early. You need to escape them:

```
echo 'document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" />");';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can separately use php and html portion in your code like this

```
<?php if(SOME_CONDITION_IN_PHP) {?>
document.write("<input type='hidden' />");
<?php }?>
```

So you can write big and complex html portion in between the if condition.

In your code when you look at it

```
echo 'document.write("<input type="hidden" />");';
```

This will be printed like this

```
document.write("<input type="hidden" />");
```

as in the javascript code if you want to use `"` in `"`  escape it with a backslash (). So the code will become like this

```
document.write("<input type=\"hidden\" />");
```

But you should separate html and php portion for a neat code

Comment: Or even better with a template engine!